# Can't access commonMain multiplatform classes from a jvm-only module

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project with following structure:

- `multiplatformmodule` - contains a single kotlin class SomeMultiPlatformClass
- `jvmmodule` - a pure jvm module which depends on `multiplatformmodule`

The problem is that within the jvmmodule I can't access any class from `multiplatformmodule` when running a test. I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/multiplatform/multiplatformmodule/SomeMultiPlatformClass`. IDE (Anroid Studio) also marks this class as unresolved. It builds, however, when the `multplatformmodule` classes are accessed from another multiplatform module.

Much more can be seen in the example project https://github.com/micHar/kmm-dependency-issues/tree/master.

Comment: Probably related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43934

Answer (score 2):

I cloned your repo and opened it with Intellij 2020.3.1 and it seems to resolve `SomeMultiPlatformClass` fine. I tried to run tests from the IDE, which didn't work for different reasons. When I changed the `@Test` to point to `kotlin.test.Test` the IDE also ran the tests fine.

[image]

https://github.com/kpgalligan/kmm-dependency-issues

Comment: Thank you! Will try with Intellij, maybe it's something with AS (I use 4.2, the one based on Intellij 2020.3.1 is in Canary right now).

Comment: Well, I tried IDEA 2020.3.1 and Android Studio 2020.3.2 Canary and they both have the same issue for me. I thought it might be apple sillicon problem for some reason, but tried on my old Intel based mac as well and it failed. Even after your code changes. No idea how to proceed...

Comment: Are you on a mac or another os? (In the previous comment I meant Android Studio 2020.3.1 Canary of course).

Comment: Macbook Pro Intel (16 inch), OS is Catalina, 10.15.6

Comment: My friend has just tried on Windows (AS 4.2.1), fresh checkout - and it failed just like mine. Why does it work for you is a mystery...

Comment: have you been able to resolve it @MichałKlimczak?

Comment: No, I worked around it. Instead of having a jvm-only module, I changed it to multiplatform module but only producing jvm artifacts. You can find it here: https://github.com/FutureMind/koru/blob/master/koru-processor/build.gradle.kts

Comment: @MichałKlimczak, my jvm module is backend-ktor, after changing it to multiplatform i'm unable to start server , fails with can not find serverkt class. Is there workaround for it

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly an Android Studio bug. Running your project with gradle, i.e. `./gradlew test` will run the test (`SomeJvmTest`) just fine.